# What is the record for the most pawn double-steps in a professional game?

Tags: pawns, records, master-games, famous-games, double-step

Quite simply, what is the record for the most pawn double-steps in a professional game? Drawn and won games are both considered.  Computer games of any kind are not to be considered.

The most I have found, in quite a few games, is 8. For example, here is a game in which all 8 double steps occur in just 15 moves.

```
[Title "John Cochrane-Bonnerjee Mohishunder, Calcutta, 1855"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5 d6 4. Nxf7 Kxf7 5. Bc4+ Be6 6. Bxe6+ Kxe6 7. O-O Kd7 8. d4 Kc8 9. c4 Nbd7 10. Nc3 Kb8 11. f4 a6 12. a4 Ka7 13. b4 Rc8 14. Be3 Kb8 15. a5 c5 16. b5 Ka7 17. d5 g6 18. Qb3 Bg7 19. Rfb1 Rb8 20. b6+ Ka8 21. Nb5 Ne8 22. Ra2 Rf8 23. Na7 Ndf6 24. Nc6 Qd7 25. Nxb8 Kxb8 26. e5 Ng4 27. e6 Qe7 28. Kh1 Qh4 29. g3 Qh3 30. Bg1 g5 31. Qa4 Nef6 32. e7 Rc8 33. fxg5 Ne4 34. Rg2 Nc3 35. e8=Q Nxa4 36. Qxa4 Rf8 37. Re1 Be5 38. Qb3 Kc8 39. Qd3 Kd7 40. Rf1 Ke7 41. Rxf8 Kxf8 42. Qf5+ Kg7 43. Qd7+ Kg6 44. Qxb7 Bd4 45. Bxd4 cxd4 46. Qc6 d3 47. Qxd6+ Kxg5 48. Qf4+ Kg6 49. Qe4+ Kg7 50. Qxd3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a game with [12 double-steps](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1776547)
 on chessgames.com

```
[Title "Alexandru Sorin Segal-Karl-Heinz Podzielny, Dortmund, Dortmund Germany, 1980"]
[FEN ""]

1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 c5 3.d5 e6 4.Nc3 exd5 5.cxd5 d6 6.e4 g6 7.f4 Bg7 8.Nf3 O-O 9.Be2 Re8 10.Nd2 a6 11.a4 Nbd7 12.O-O Rb8 13.a5 Qc7 14.Qc2 b5 15.axb6 Nxb6 16.Bf3 c4 17.Kh1 Bh6 18.Ne2 Qc5 19.b4 cxb3 20.Qxb3 Qc7 21.Qd3 Bd7 22.Rxa6 Nbxd5 23.Qd4 Bb5 24.Ra7 Qc5 25.Qxc5 dxc5 26.exd5 Bxe2 27.Bxe2 Rxe2 28.d6 Bf8 29.f5 gxf5 30.Ra6 Rd8 31.Nc4 Re4 32.Ne3 Rxd6 33.Ra8 f4 34.Nf5 Rd5 35.g4 fxg3 36.Nxg3 Re8 37.Ra2 Bg7 38.Nf5 Kf8 39.Nxg7 Kxg7 40.Rg2+ Kf8 41.Bh6+ Ke7 42.Bg5 Rxg5 43.Rxg5 Rg8 44.Rxc5 Rg6 45.Rc8 Nd5 46.Ra8 Rf6 47.Rb1 Rf5 48.Rh8 h5 49.Re1+ Kf6 50.Rh6+ Kg7 51.Rd6 Kh7 52.Ra6 Nc7 53.Raa1 Ne6 54.Rf1 Rxf1+ 55.Rxf1 Kg6 56.Kg2 Nd4 57.Ra1 Kg5 58.Ra5+ f5 59.h4+ Kf4 60.Ra6 Ne2 61.Rg6 Nd4 62.Rg8 Nc6 63.Rg5 Ne5 64.Kh3 Nd3 65.Rxh5 Nf2+ 66.Kg2 Kg4 67.Rh8 Nd3 68.Rg8+ Kxh4 69.Kf3 Kh5 70.Re8 Kg5
```

Answer (score 4):

This is clearly contrived, but it was an actual tournament game so it wins that record. :)

```
  [Title "Danny Jazmati-Marcel Harff, NRW-ch U12, 2002"]
  [FEN ""]

1. a4 a5 2. b4 b5 3. c4 c5 4. d4 d5 5. e4 e5 6. f4 f5 7. g4 g5 8. h4 h5 9. Ra2 Rh6 10. Rh3 Raa6 11. Bd2 Be7 12. Bc3 Bf6 13. Nd2 Ne7 14. Nb3 Ng6 15. Ne2 Bb7 16. Kf2 Nd7 1/2-1/2
```

Comment: It was an official game, albeit, not by masters.

Comment: I am surprised that this did not result in a double disqualification

Comment: @RewanDemontay What I don't understand is what the arbiter did!

Comment: Come one, it is simple: They were little kids, and it was the last round. This was not a couple of GMs in a big-money tournament. The arbiter might have said something, but in that situation, I would not punish kids for, well, being kids. :) one more thing you need to consider, and that is that it was a different time. People did not get so easily bent out of shape back then over little things.

Comment: @David Why would/should the arbiter say something in today's world?

Comment: @user1583209 Because it looks prearranged and it was the last round. Even moreso if the players were in contention for prizes.

Comment: @PhishMaster Precisely because they were kids, that's why we should teach them why cheating is wrong, and why prearranging a game is cheating